# Why do I get an UndefVarError in Julia macro

Tags: scope, macros, julia

I am learning Julia, and in particular I am trying to get a grasp of macros, so I found, amongst other things [Some useful macros for Julia - Github](https://gist.github.com/MikeInnes/8299575), and in the process of deciphering them I got this behavior in the REPL :

```
julia> macro once_then(expr::Expr)
         @assert expr.head == :while
         esc(quote
           $(expr.args[2]) # body of loop
           $expr # loop
         end)
       end
@once_then (macro with 1 method)

julia> i = 0
0

julia> @once_then while i < 10
       i += 1
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: i not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at ./REPL[34]:2 [inlined]
 [2] top-level scope at ./REPL[31]:5

julia> i
1
```

It clearly had access to `i` in the first iteration of the loop, since it incremented it, but then did `i` become `Undef`ed somewhere between the end of the first loop and the beginning of the second ?
From what I can see the parenthesis after `esc` should include everything up to the end of the loop...

I literally just copy-pasted the code into the terminal, and I get the same behavior from the `@until` macro found at [Julia language - Until loop](https://riptutorial.com/julia-lang/example/19404/until-loop), so I don't think the problem would come from the code itself... is there something crucial I'm missing ?

(btw, I'm running 1.0.4, so it shouldn't be an issue of backwards compatibility...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro is fine. the problem is the scope of the variables involved. (for more information, look at this: [JuliaLang - Scope of Variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/index.html)
in a nutshell, the variable `i` in `i = 0` is in a global scope, where the loop is in a local scope. in the REPL, you can add the keywork `global` this to make your code work:

```
julia> @once_then while i < 10
       global i += 1
       end
```

other option is to do all this in a function, so all variables have local scope:

```
function fn()
i = 0
@once_then while i < 10
        i += 1
        end
    return i
end
```

Comment: So is the example in the second link an error, then ?